# How can I make my iOS app vibrate continuously until a specific time without being limited by Apple's background activity restrictions?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make my app vibrate continuously until the user enters the app at a specific time. However, I know that Apple has restricted background activities, and although I have implemented it with local notifications, it only vibrates once. There is an app in the App Store called "Alarmy," which has the functionality I want to implement. I would like to know how to make the vibration continue without stopping, using CoreAudio or AVFoundation, without the need for music to be playing. Can you help me with this?

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = selectRunning.name + "휴식 완료"
    content.body = "휴식이 완료되었습니다. 운동을 진행해주세요."
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: "sound.wav"))
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(restTime), repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notificationID", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    while true {
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can. Apple explicitly blocks that sort of thing.

Comment: I resolved the issue by playing a silent.mp3 file in the background and setting a timer to vibrate every second

Comment: @jinwoo I'm looking for something like that. Can you post the solution as an answer?